# I accidentally clicked "Clean and Build Main Project" in NetBeans 7.0. Resource problems ensued

Tags: java, netbeans, build

I clicked "Clean and Build Main Project" by accident and I thought it would do no harm. However, when I edited a file in the project's `src` folder (`ProjectName\src\myproject\folder1\folder2`) it didn't reflect the changes on the program itself. I used `getClass().getResource("/folder1/folder2")` to get the file's location. Before, it would return the `src` folder but now it returns the `build` folder.

Is there a way to return it back the way it was before? Though I have no problem with that as I only have to edit the files I needed on the build folder, I am not sure whether the edits I made on my `.java` files AFTER the Clean and Build are saved on the `build` folder and not on the `src` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the build folder is in the classpath, getting resources will return items from there.

I'm not sure what type of files you're talking about editing, but you shouldn't edit files in the build folder, because they will be subject to deletion if you do a clean.

I don't know if you're using netbeans' build automatically feature, if that's the case, you should just be able to just edit code, run your program and see your changes (assuming your program compiled successfully). Then shut down your program, edit your code and repeat. I don't use this feature, the early versions didn't work, and I don't know if the current one does or not. I turn it off.

Note, if you're doing Java EE development, there are auto-deployers that can automatically re-deploy your code. I don't know if you're doing this or not, but it generally tends to work, but you can write code that will make it not work correctly e.g. have static variables in your servlets or register database drivers from your code (which should be done in the container).

Comment: I'm trying to edit text files. I edited them on the src folder and if I simply run it, the files in the build folder are not updated. But if I do a Clean and Build, the files in the build folder are updated. I'm using the auto-build feature. I've figured it out now. Thanks a lot.